# Primes in integral closure of Gaussian integers field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> Let us have $A[\sqrt{13}] = \mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{13})/2]$. How can all the prime elements of it be described?

$z \in Z$ is prime if quotient ring $Z[\Theta]/(z)_{Z[\Theta]}$ is a field.

I have been told there is is something to be done with quadratic nonresidues and Legendre symbol.